# String replacement in BibTool

Tags: bibliographies, bibtool

I would like to use [BibTool](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtool) to enclose some strings in a `bib`-file in curly braces. The test `bib` entry looks like this:

```
@Article{Cite1,
author       = {Adelbert, A.},
date         = {2020},
journaltitle = {A Journal},
title        = {A title with just \textit{Test} structure and some chemistry \ce{CO2}},
number       = {2},
pages        = {1--4},
volume       = {1},
}
```

I have created the following BibTool resource file:

```
resource {biblatex}
preserve.keys = on
preserve.key.case = on
rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{.*}\)" "{{\1}}"}
```

The `rewrite.rule` is supposed to be the following:

1. Find all strings within any field that start with `\`, like `\ce{}`, `\textit{}`, etc. This is done by the `\\` at the beginning of the regular expression.
2. When this string is found save the following in a group, denoted by `\(\)`: A random string at the beginning, followed by `{`, a random string, followed by `}`; i.e. the string `textit{Test}`.
3. Write this string back into the same position, but enclose it in a double-set of curly braces `"{{\1}}"`.

What it manages so far:

1. It apparently finds all commands starting with `\`.
2. It saves the strings and writes them back into the file.

So far, the code returns the following

```
@Article{Cite1,
Author       = {Adelbert, A.},
Date         = {2020},
JournalTitle = {A Journal},
Title        = {A title with just {{textit{Test} structure and some chemistry {{ce{CO2}}}}}},
Number       = {2},
Pages        = {1--4},
Volume       = {1},
}
```

You see it finds the strings and puts `{{` at the beginning of each string. Unfortunately, it puts `}}` at the end of the field, **not** the string, so I now have 6 curly braces at the end of the title field. The braces do match, just two of them should be after `{{textit{Test}` not at the very end. I tried various constructions like `rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{.*}\)$" "{{\1}}"}`, `rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{.*}\) ?$" "{{\1}}"}`, `rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{.*}\)*$" "{{\1}}"}` but this all did not work.

When trying to get the `\` back at the beginning of the string, using `rewrite.rule = {"\\\(.*{.*}\)" "{{\\\1}}"}` I get the `\` back, but also thousands of `{}` until I get a `Rewrite limit exceeded` error.

I am not very good with regular expressions and would be happy for any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an exchange with the creator of BibTool, he kindly suggested a working solution to me:

```
rewrite.rule {"\\\(\([a-zA-Z]+\|.\){[^{}]*}\)" "{##\1}"}
rewrite.rule {"##" "\\"}
```

For more details, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61384886/regular-expression-to-embed-string-with-backslash-and-curly-braces-in-more-curly).